# update_post_meta not working

Tags: plugins, php

Making a plugin to make my life easier at creating over 3000+ pages. Take a look at the code I have so far.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
$one = array(
 'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
 'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
 'post_content' => 'This is a post.',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_parent' => $_POST['title']
 );
$two = array(
 'post_title' => $_POST['title'] . ' Air Conditioning',
 'post_date' => $_SESSION['cal_startdate'],
 'post_content' => 'This is a post.',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_parent' => $_POST['title']
 );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($one);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($two);

update_post_meta($post_id, "_wp_page_template", $_POST['title'] . '.php');
echo $_POST['title'] . '.php';
}
else {

}
```

For some reason, the _wp_page_template is NOT WORKING and it's quite frustrating. If I go to the pages this code generates.. it still says "default template" when it should be $_POST['title'].php

If anyone can offer help on this, it would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Brandon

Comment: Two questions: 1. What hook are you using? 2. Have you dumped $post_id to see if you're actually getting an iD?

Comment: There's no hook it just runs immediately after the form is submitted. I'm not sure how to dump the id? I'd guess just printing it. I'll try that.
**EDIT:** Yes it assigns a $post_id.

Comment: You should be using a callback function for a WP hook to make sure all of the WP functions are loaded when running your code. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Actions

Comment: Brian would it be possible for you to contact me via skype @ brandonjjon?

I've referenced the codex but can't quite make sense of it.

Comment: Just curious as to how you're checking if this is updated. Are you looking at the custom fields? If so, the underscored fields do not display there. If you're looking at the Page Template dropdown, you must have an actual page template with the name of that PHP file in theme directory.

Are you looking at the database entries to see if this is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely not assigning the right page template. Make sure your template name is the same case as the file in your theme directory. Also make sure the file name you provide as the template actually exists in the theme directory otherwise it will be marked as the Default page template.